# При выходе из Activity android я теряю bluetooth подключение

Tags: android

Я начинающий Android программер, сорри если вопрос тупой.
допустим у меня есть три Activity,
MAIN
Settings-General
Settings-BLE
В  Settings-BLE я устанавливаю соединение с другими устройствами, все работает, мы обмениваемся инфой. Но если я выхожу в MainActivity я теряю соединение.
Мой вариант (костыль) я с помоющь onActivityResult получаю данные для соединения которые пользователь установил в  Settings-BLE и просто переподключаюсь уже в Main. Завтра у меня к примеру, может быть 20 Activity, не буду ж я везде такое мутить... Как правильно действовать?

Comment: 1. показать код, как вы подключаетесь. 2. перенести логику в класс, который не зависит от текущено `Activity`, например в `Service`

Comment: Точно, уберу логику в отдельный класс.... Спасибо!